# Trying to convert a function based view to a generic detail view

Tags: python, django, view

Creating a comment system for a ticket django project. I've completed most of the functionality for the comment, except I'm not quite sure how to implement the POST method so that I can use the frontend to create comments. If I use the admin site, it works and shows up in the view, but I get an error when I try to submit using the frontend form. I'm not  sure how to proceed, any help is much appreciated.

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: tickets_comment.ticket_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issuetracker\tickets\views.py", line 73, in post
    user_comment.save()
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\mptt\models.py", line 1096, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 885, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1301, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1441, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\bug_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

Here's the original function based view

```
def ticket_single(request, post):

    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, slug=ticket, status='published')

    allcomments = ticket.comments.filter(status=True)
    
    user_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.ticket = ticket
            user_comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + ticket.slug)
    else:
        comment_form = NewCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'ticket_detail.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'comments':  user_comment, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form, 'allcomments': allcomments, })
```

Here's what I have so far in the DetailView

```
class TicketDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Ticket

    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(ticket=self.object)
        context['comment_form'] = NewCommentForm()
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                user_comment.save()
                return render(request, 'ticket_detail.html', {'comments': user_comment, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this error:

```
(NOT NULL constraint failed: tickets_comment.ticket_id ...)
```

It means, that you try to create `Comment` object (from `tickets` app), but you didn't provide `ticket` or `ticket_id`. You didn't include `user_comment.ticket = ticket` in class based view and you should, because it's required by your model.